# How can I change MetaHuman pose and face expression without losing everything on autosave?

Tags: animation, unreal-4, unreal, unreal-5

I uploaded a MetaHuman in a level.

Then, I want to do changes its face, body and so on, in the same fashion as if you load an animate sequence. I want to control its facial expression with face control. But, when I press <kbd>Ctrl + Z</kbd> or the auto-saving occurs, the whole MetaHuman pose changes to its default position and I lose all my work entirely.

So, how can I change the MetaHuman pose and control its facial expressions, without the trouble that every time I press <kbd>Ctrl + Z</kbd> or the auto-saving occurs, the whole pose changes, discarding my work entirely?

I want static poses, not animations!